# Removing suffixes from list Python

Tags: python

I have 2 lists
where

```
name = ['Annie A3', 'apple.com', 'John PLG', 'Piggy Alpha CLa'] 
suffixes = ['A3','.Com','pLG','Cla']
```

I am trying to remove the suffixes from the name list. 
What is the best approach in this scenario?

Do i convert both list string into upper/lower case letter and iterate through a for loop to substring?

Comment: Are the two arrays always of the same lenght and do every suffixes element need to be removed from the name's same index element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the suffix in the following way:

```
if name.lower().endswith(suffix.lower()):
    name = name[0:-len(suffix)]
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, two loops.

```
names = ['Annie A3', 'apple.com', 'John PLG', 'Piggy Alpha CLa']
suffixes = ['A3','.Com','pLG','Cla']
new_names = []
for name in names:
  for suffix in suffixes:
    if name.lower().endswith(suffix.lower()):
      name = # Do what you want with the suffix
  new_names.append(name)
```

Comment: Thanks! how do i delete the suffix from the name?

Comment: `name = name[:-len(suffix)]`

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension approach. This will just remove all the suffixes and maintain the case of the names as it is in the final output.

```
names = ['Annie A3', 'apple.com', 'John PLG', 'Piggy Alpha CLa'] 
suffixes = ['A3','.Com','pLG','Cla']

[name[:-len(suffix)].rstrip() for suffix in suffixes for name in names if suffix.lower() in name.lower()]
```

Output will be:
['Annie', 'apple', 'John', 'Piggy Alpha']